# Value sent to channel by method in go, cannot be received on the outside

Tags: go, channel

I was trying to implement sort-of a reactive golang implementation. I have an array of observers. They are just a bunch of channels. Everything is encapsulated in a package where other code could subscribe and unsubscribe. When ever an order is created, the change will be pushed. But I have failed to register channel receive with in a method.

```golang
package rxOrder

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "errors"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

// Order This is the sample data structure
type Order struct {
    id        bson.ObjectId
    moldID    bson.ObjectId
    bomID     bson.ObjectId
    deviceID  bson.ObjectId
    userIds   []bson.ObjectId
    name      string
    orderType string // withOrder, noOrder, makeUp, test
    startTime time.Time
    deadline  time.Time
    volume    int32
}

// OrderMutation This is the struct for sending
// mutations to observers
type OrderMutation struct {
    order  Order
    action string
}

// RxOrder This is the node for reactive Order
// management
type RxOrder struct {
    orders    []Order
    observers map[string]chan OrderMutation
}

// init This method initialize RxOrder, including
// orders slice and subscriber map, user cannot
// initialize a RxOrder object more than once
func (rx *RxOrder) init() error {
    if len(rx.orders) == 0 && len(rx.observers) == 0 {
        rx.orders = make([]Order, 1)
        rx.observers = make(map[string]chan OrderMutation)
        return nil
    }

    return errors.New("Cannot reinitialize orders")
}

// subscribe, add observer to list
func (rx *RxOrder) subscribe(key string, ch chan OrderMutation) error {
    if _, ok := rx.observers[key]; ok {
        return errors.New("Observer already existed")
    }

    rx.observers[key] = ch

    return nil
}

// unsubscribe, delete observer from list
func (rx *RxOrder) unsubscribe(key string) error {
    if _, ok := rx.observers[key]; !ok {
        return errors.New("Observer does not exist")
    }

    delete(rx.observers, key)

    return nil
}

// createOrder The method for creating an order
func (rx *RxOrder) createOrder(order Order) error {

    if !order.id.Valid() {
        return errors.New("Invalid order id")
    }

    if !order.bomID.Valid() {
        return errors.New("Invalid bom id")
    }

    if !order.deviceID.Valid() {
        return errors.New("Invalid device id")
    }

    if !order.moldID.Valid() {
        return errors.New("Invalid mold id")
    }

    if len(order.userIds) < 1 {
        return errors.New("Empty users list")
    }

    for index, userID := range order.userIds {
        if !userID.Valid() {
            return errors.New(fmt.Sprint("Invalid user id at index: ", index))
        }
    }

    if len(order.name) < 1 {
        return errors.New("Empty order name")
    }

    if order.orderType != "withOrder" && order.orderType != "noOrder" && order.orderType != "makeUp" && order.orderType != "test" {
        return errors.New("Wrong order type")
    }

    if order.startTime.After(order.deadline) {
        return errors.New("Deadline cannot come before start time")
    }

    if order.volume < 1 {
        return errors.New("Empty order is not accepted")
    }

    rx.orders = append(rx.orders, order)

    for _, ch := range rx.observers {
        ch <- OrderMutation{order, "create"}
    }

    return nil
}
```

```golang
func TestCreateOrder(t *testing.T) {
    orderManagement := RxOrder{}

    orderManagement.init()

    orderManagement.subscribe("123", make(chan OrderMutation))
    orderManagement.subscribe("345", make(chan OrderMutation))
    orderManagement.subscribe("768", make(chan OrderMutation))

    order := Order{}
    order.id = bson.NewObjectId()
    order.bomID = bson.NewObjectId()
    order.deviceID = bson.NewObjectId()
    order.moldID = bson.NewObjectId()
    order.name = "iPhone 8+"
    order.orderType = "withOrder"
    order.volume = 5
    order.startTime = time.Now()
    order.deadline = order.startTime.AddDate(0, 1, 1)
    order.userIds = make([]bson.ObjectId, 1)
    order.userIds = append(order.userIds, bson.NewObjectId())

    go func(t *testing.T) {
        fmt.Println(<-orderManagement.observers["123"])
    }(t)

    orderManagement.createOrder(order)
    //orderManagement.observers["123"] <- OrderMutation{order, "w"}

    t.Fail()
}
```

when I do test, the above code prints nothing, but if I uncomment line:

```golang
orderManagement.observers["123"] <- OrderMutation{order, "w"}
```

Everything works. It seems I cannot operate on channel within a method. How can I encapsulate channel operation with in package?

Comment: You absolutely can operate on channels within a method. Your test fails because there is a t.Fail() at the end that is always executed. You need to fail conditionally.

Comment: Only through t.Fail() can I let test print to console, the values sent through method was not received by receive end on the out side

Comment: I think you have a race condition there. There is no guarantee the goroutine will print the message before your test ends

Comment: orderManagement.observers["123"] <- OrderMutation{order, "w"} why does this line works?

Comment: verbose mode when testing `go test ./... -v`
this allows you to always print logs.

Comment: buffered channels only block when the buffer is [full](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/3). so uncommenting that line causes your test thread to block and wait for a read in the goroutine, allowing the prints in the goroutine to happen before the main thread hit's `t.Fail()`.

Comment: I will try it, thanks!

Comment: I have resolved it sort of, is to add a resolve method to receive the signal, and call it from outside, still I want to know is there a way to receive it directly from outside

Comment: func (rx *RxOrder) resolve(key string) OrderMutation {
 return <-rx.observers[key]
// This is the resolve method

Comment: go func() {
  orderManagement.createOrder(order)
 }()

 for key := range orderManagement.observers {
  fmt.Println(orderManagement.resolve(key))
 } // This is what's called from the outside

Answer (score 0):

The situation depends on the following outputs：

Does you `createOrder` return an error?

If `createOrder` has any error，then it will not send any message on the channel, so by commenting that line your main test function will exit without waiting.

You have no output, if you add the mentioned line, your main  test function will wait on the channel operation until your coroutine receives the message and prints the output.

If your `createOrder` has no error， you will face a race condition because the message sent on channel except "123" will block your main test function forever.

Comment: No I have checked, even without any error, there are no values received.

Comment: It always prints 
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

Comment: ```go
err := orderManagement.createOrder(order)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("orderManagement error:", err)
}
```
add this to check the createOrder err, and you can print some log at here:
  ```go
 for _, ch := range rx.observers {
        ch <- OrderMutation{order, "create"}
 }
```

Comment: Yes, this helps

Answer (score 0):

After I did this, everything works.

```go
go func() {
  for _, ch: = range rx.observers {
    ch <-OrderMutation {
      order, "create"
    }
  }
}()

// create a goroutine to send message

    func() {
        orderManagement.createOrder(order)
    }()

    select {
    case val := <-orderManagement.observers["123"]:
        fmt.Println(val)
    }

// then receive on the outside like this
```

Even without resolve method everything works.

Comment: However, I am still open to other options